# Batch file to display only few lines from an existing text file

Tags: text

Hi I have been trying to get only a few lines from an existing text displayed. Here is the code i have been trying.

```
type C:\SystemInfo1.txt | findstr /C:"OS Name:" | findstr /C:"OS Version:">c:\SystemInfo.txt
c:\systeminfo.txt
```

this works only for one i.e., 'OS Name'. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Why are you searching for OS Name twice?

Comment: I am sorry dint see that it was twice the second would be 'OS Version'. From a system information text file i need only a few information not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
type C:\SystemInfo1.txt | findstr /C:"OS Name:" /C:"OS Version:"
```

The key is to use findstr only once, but pass multiple strings to it as needed.

You may be able to simplify further by getting rid of the "type" command and pipeline:

```
findstr /C:"OS Name:" /C:"OS Version:"  C:\SystemInfo1.txt
```

If the strings you are searching for are always at the beginning of a line, this may help you overcome the problem you commented about (OS vs BIOS):

```
findstr /R "^OS (Version|Name)" C:\SystemInfo1.txt
```

This is using a regular expression to search for "OS" at the start of a line, followed by "Version" or "Name".

Comment: Thanks i tried the first one, but i get everything which has the term 'Version' in it.

Comment: Really? What version of Windows? I'm testing this on Windows XP SP3, and i get all lines that have the terms "OS Name:" or "OS Version:" in them, but not simply "Version".

Comment: I meant i get BIOS version too, i have the same OS

Comment: :-) Sure, "BIOS Version" contains "OS Version". Depending on the formatting of your file, you may be able to constrain your matches to exclude the one you don't want, or just pipe it to another findstr to exclude "BIOS":     
`[previous code...] | findstr /V BIOS`

Comment: hmm...i thought "/c:" command would strictly look for "OS Version"

Comment: It does. And it finds "OS Version" contained inside "BIOS Version"

Comment: one more question, findstr /C:"OS Name:" /C:"OS Version:"  C:\SystemInfo1.txt doesnt work for /V ?

Comment: It should: `findstr /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" C:\SystemInfo1.txt | findstr /V BIOS`
In this case, you need 2 "findstr", the first one finds all lines containing the strings you specified, and the second one takes the output of the first and further refines it.

Comment: I had to post another...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795051/display-all-the-lines-after-a-particular-line-in-a-text-file-using-batch